# Connections between concepts

Tags: logic, epistemology, philosophy-of-mind

How can it be possible that two concepts have a connection between them? Even when we admit that every such connection is empirical, we have a necessary connection between the concept "connection" and "arbitrariness". What is their nature?

Comment: Not clear... there are e.g. *definitions* that generate links between concepts.

Comment: Kant addressed this subject: "Since that within which the sensations can alone be ordered and placed in a certain form cannot itself be in turn sensation, the matter of all appearance is only given to us *a posteriori*, but its form must all lie ready for it in the mind *a priori*, and can therefore be considered separately from all sensation." (*Critique of Pure Reason*, A20/B34)

Comment: Who are "we"? Many accept so-called analytic connections "in virtue of the meanings" which are not empirical and are necessary, see [analytic/synthetic distinction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analytic-synthetic). Indeed, since Frege many consider most of mathematics to be analytic, and natural science, especially physics, to be permeated by essentially mathematical connections (say, between force, acceleration, momentum, kinetic energy..). But even without analyticity what is the problem with concepts overlapping or subsuming each other, which would establish the requisite connections?

Comment: @Conifold Wittgenstein's Familienähnlichkeit might give a sufficient answer to that one.

Comment: Family resemblance is indeed a deflated version of analyticity, concepts are "similar" if competent users of language are disposed to use them as such. Since such use depends on the prevailing practice with concepts rather than on observations, these connections are not (straightforwardly) empirical. But this is not the only option, and even Wittgenstein himself acknowledges that the prevailing communal use is not purely cultural or arbitrary, but is ultimately "hardened" from coping with physical reality.

Comment: If you admit that the internal representation of fire is a concept and that the internal representation of smoke is a concept then there would be a neural connection between these two concepts?

Comment: According to Kant, the connection arises through judgment which, in turn, is the subsuming of an object under a concept. The experience of smoke, for example, may be subsumed under the concept of *consequence* which leads to trying to make another connection, because, for every consequent, there is an antecedent. The possibility of doing this requires certain *a priori* concepts, i.e. the categories. I believe Kant was correct about this, because the ability to hypothesize about a consequent presupposes a basic familiarity with the notion of it.

Comment: @Pé de Leão Yeah, I think this answer is the closest to what I want.